# java.lang.StackOverflowError at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis$1.walk(GridLayout.java:1315)

Tags: android

I get a StackOverflowError error only if the app runs certain devices, it works fine with others.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis$1.walk(GridLayout.java:1315)
...
...
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis$1.walk(GridLayout.java:1315)
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis$1.sort(GridLayout.java:1333)
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.topologicalSort(GridLayout.java:1304)
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.topologicalSort(GridLayout.java:1342)
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.createArcs(GridLayout.java:1376)
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getArcs(GridLayout.java:1390)
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.computeLocations(GridLayout.java:1575)
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getLocations(GridLayout.java:1596)
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getMeasure(GridLayout.java:1617)
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout$Axis.getMeasure(GridLayout.java:1625)
at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.onMeasure(GridLayout.java:939)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(HorizontalScrollView.java:1159)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:303)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1163)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:312)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4805)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:676)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4805)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:828)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4805)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2097)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please any hint?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "certain devices"?

Comment: @Voidpaw thanks Voidpaw but unfortunately I don know what phone the user is using. The error happen only on that phone

Answer (score 2):

Just debugged a similar situation, turned out the two-dimensional array being used to setup the support-GridLayout was too large for all the 2.3.x devices I tested. Dropped the max number of rows down and StackOverflowError avoided. Hope this information helps your case!

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: Confirmed. Error occured at rowCount=300, but didn't occur at rowCount=150

Comment: I had the same issue on Android 4.4.4. Decreased the row size to 300. Thanks for answer